# laravel 7 csrf token mismatch

Tags: laravel, csrf-token, laravel-7

I am using laravel 7 and default auth with ajax login & registration and bootstrap 4 modal window. But after login resend verification link and while registration shows "CSRF token Mismatch error", here is my code below:

```
    #ajax setup#
    $(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    });

    //login with ajax
    $(function(){
        $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr("action");
            var type = form.attr("method");
            var data = new FormData(form[0]);

            //console.log(data.response);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: type,
                processData:false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(){
                    //reset form data
                    $( '#loginForm' ).each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });

                    $('#login').modal('hide');

                    $(".top_header_area").load('/'+ ' .top_header_area');

                    //success message
                    toastr.success('Login Successfull <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>','Success',{
                        closeButton: true,
                        progressBar: true
                    });

                },
                error:function(xhr,status,error){
                    //console.log(xhr.status);
                    //console.log(xhr.responseJSON.message);
                    if(xhr.status === 403){
                        $('#login').modal('hide');
                        //reload header panel
                        $(".top_header_area").load('/'+ ' .top_header_area');
                        $('#verify').modal('show');
                        toastr.error(xhr.responseJSON.message,'Error',{
                            closeButton: true,
                            progressBar: true
                        });
                    }
                    errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value){
                        //shows error message
                        toastr.error(value,'Error',{
                            closeButton: true,
                            progressBar: true
                        });
                    });
                },

            });
        });
    });
    //Register with ajax
    $(function(){
        $("#registerForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr("action");
            var type = form.attr("method");
            var data = new FormData(form[0]);

            //console.log(data.response);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: type,
                processData:false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(){
                    //reset form data
                    $( '#registerForm' ).each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });

                    $('#register').modal('hide');

                    //success message
                    toastr.success('Registration Successfull <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>','Success',{
                        closeButton: true,
                        progressBar: true
                    });

                },
                error:function(xhr,status,error){

                    if(xhr.status === 403){
                        $('#register').modal('hide');
                        //reload header panel
                        $(".top_header_area").load('/'+ ' .top_header_area');
                        $('#verify').modal('show');
                        toastr.error(xhr.responseJSON.message,'Error',{
                            closeButton: true,
                            progressBar: true
                        });
                    }

                    errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value){
                        //shows error message
                        toastr.error(value,'Error',{
                            closeButton: true,
                            progressBar: true
                        });
                    });
                },

            });
        });
    });
            //request verification email
    $(function(){
        $("#resendLink").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr("action");
            var type = form.attr("method");
            var data = new FormData(form[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: type,
                data: data,
                processData:false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(){
                    $(".top_header_area").load('/'+ ' .top_header_area');
                    //reset form data
                    $( '#resendLink' ).each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });

                    $('#verify').modal('hide');

                    //success message
                    toastr.success('Verification Link Send <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>','Success',{
                        closeButton: true,
                        progressBar: true
                    });

                },
            });
        });
    });
```

when I check the network tab in the browser Request Cookie and Response Cookie value is different and I am using login, registration, resend verification link all forms are in modals in the same app.blade.php blade layout.
after login when click on "resend verification link" button form it shows "csrf token mismatch" but after refresh the page it works!
I am sending 2 ajax request from the same page....
1. login
2. resend verification link

but registration form sending 1 ajax request but again showing same error.

forms are below:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginTitle"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> LOGIN</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body contact-form">
        <form id="loginForm" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="loginEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="LoginPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" autocomplete="current-password">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember">
                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                </label>
              </div>                
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase button" type="submit">{{ __('Login') }}</button>
          <hr>
            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
            <a class="btn btn-link link" href="#" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reset">
                {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
            </a>
            @endif
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Don't have account? <a href="#" class="link" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">Register</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- ****** Register modal Start ****** -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="registerTitle"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> REGISTER</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body contact-form">
        <form id="registerForm" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" autocomplete="username" autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="registerEmail" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="registerPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="register-password-confirm" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" autocomplete="new-password">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase button" type="submit">{{ __('Register') }}</button>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Already REGISTERED<a href="#" class="link" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> LOGIN</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


      <!-- ****** Verify modal Start ****** -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verify" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="verifyTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="verifyTitle"><i class="fas fa-certificate heading"></i> {{ __('Verify Your Email Address') }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          @if (session('resent'))
              <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                  {{ __('A fresh verification link has been sent to your email address.') }}
              </div>
          @endif

          {{ __('Before proceeding, please check your email for a verification link.') }}
          {{ __('If you did not receive the email') }},
          <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="resend()" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline link">{{ __('click here to request another') }}</a> -->
          <form id="resendLink" class="d-inline" method="POST" action="{{ route('verification.resend') }}">
              @csrf
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline">{{ __('click here to request another') }}</button>.
          </form>          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you have to add "**X-CSRF-TOKEN**" to main layout `<head></head>` tag. The VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could store the token in an HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

For More details please visit [CSRF Protection Laravel-docs 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)